# REACT: My method not filtered my data according to its name

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I am working on a project in React with Redux. I am trying to do realtime search.

(In below) I handled the data with onchange. Search item changes and setted input every time. Then, I tried to check with all input change in use effect.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const HandleRefresh = () => {
    dispatch(FetchCityData());
  };
  console.log(input);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(FilterCity(input));
  }, [input, dispatch]);
```

After that, I Coded my FetchCityData Reducer. My all cities in myCities array. I try to find equal names with filter method. You can see in the following code:

```
 case ActionTypes.GETBY_MYLIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        myCities: [
          ...initialState.myCities,
          ...state.myCities.filter(
            (item) => toString(item.name) === toString(payload.name)
          ),
        ],
      };
```

Before that I coded my actions :

```
export const FilterCity = (q) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.GETBY_MYLIST,
    payload: q,
  });
};
```

q is my input as you know.

However,it doesnt work. I see the change of input on console but not filtered. What can be the problem?

Comment: ```toString(5)``` in the browser console ```'[object Undefined]'```.

Comment: @Medi but its name is a string. I delete to string. It works but wrong  kdskdsk

Comment: ```window.toString()``` results in ```'[object Window]'```, try ```String()``` method.

Answer (score 2):

That's how You can approach that issue. Instead of the `useEffect` I'd put that in the `onChange` event attached to the input. Store the input value in the component level state and everytime the value of the input changes (onChange) You can trigger the proper dispatches responsible for filtering the data. And of course everytime the filter method is done it should update the list so that UI can build on top of that.

You can always try to configure redux devtools which will help You a lot to track what's going on in Your store. Trust me it will help You a lot

Workflow:

1. User lands on your page
2. Api call gets triggered
3. Api result gets stored in redux
4. Based on the result array You build the list (.map()) on the UI
5. You attach the onChange event to the input
6. Everytime the user makes the change, Your result array (stored in redux store) gets filtered using the input value.
7. Once the filtering is done You put the new array to the result array in redux store
8. Ui notices that the list based on which he's creating the list has changed so he decides to re-render the page
9. Your filtered list now gets displayed on the UI

This might be similar to what You try to achieve

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-search-filter-through-data-in-react-26f1545fe3a1